# Collinear points on quartic

Tags: polynomials

I understand the word collinear to mean the points all lie on a straight line but can’t figure out how to tackle the question. The question is: Show that if four distinct points of the curve $$y = 2x^4 + 7x^3 + 3x - 5$$ are collinear then their average $x$-coordinate is some constant $k$. Find $k$.
I can gather than the gradient between all the points is the same but can’t seem to get much further. Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: The value is $$k=-\frac{7}{8}$$
I'll try to prove it, be faithful...

Answer (score 2):

Solving the system

$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 y=2 x^4+7 x^3+3 x-5 \\
 y=m x+n \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

Can give $4$ collinear points for some values of $m,n$

Anyway the solving equation is

$2 x^4+7 x^3+3 x-5 =m x+n$

$x^4 - \left(-\dfrac{7}{2}\right)x^3+\dfrac{3-m}{2}x-\dfrac{5+n}{2}=0$

the sum of the roots is the coefficient of $x^3$, real or complex doesn't matter.

Therefore their average is $\color{red}{k=-\dfrac{7}{8}}$

Consider a quartic with its four roots $a,b,c,d$

We can write $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)=0$

expand and collect $x$

$x^4- (a+b+c+d)x^3+ (a b+a c+a d+b c+b d+c d)x^2- (a b c+a b d+a c d+b c d)x+a b c d=0$

And this finish the proof

Hope this helps

Comment: Ahh very nicely done, cheers